# Render remote partial via controller on load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rubygems

**How do I render a partial view via its controller when loading a separate view in Ruby on Rails?**

**Thanks for your help in advance**

**Problem**: I have a `show.html.erb` for my `Patients` controller, when this loads I have a series of tabs, one of which is a list of notes added to that patient record. `Notes` is a separate model. I want to load the list of notes when loading `show.html.erb`.

I can use the code below to render the view directly and can pass variables in this way, but I would rather go through the controller and deliver `notes/_list.js.erb`, via the `Patients Controller`.

```
<%= render "notes/list", :remote => true %>
```

I have a solution that loads the partial via a `link_to` but because the link is in a tab it then breaks my tab javascript, and would rather just load the information on initial page load rather than have the user interact with an element.

```
<%= link_to "Notes".html_safe,{:controller => "patients", :action => "notes", :remote => true } %>
```

It needs to be in a partial as I am then using `pagy` to paginate the results and if I display it via a controller dependent partial then the pagy navigation links function as expected.

---

**Relevant Routes**

```
get 'patients/:id/show' => 'patients#show', as: :show_patient
get 'patients/:id/notes' => 'patients#notes', as: :notes_patient
```

**Relevant Patients Controller**

```
def notes

    @pagy, @notes = pagy( Note.where(:patient_id => params[:id]).reverse_order, items: 2 )

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render "notes/list" }
        format.js { render "notes/list"  }
    end


end
```

**notes/list.js.erb**

```
$('#notes-list').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('notes/list')) %>');
```

**notes/_list.html.erb**

```
    <% @notes.each do |note| %>
        <%= render partial: note %>
    <% end %>

    <%== pagy_materialize_nav(@pagy) %>
    <span class="pagy-info"><%== pagy_info(@pagy) %></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this in the controller:

```rb
# or whatever this partial is called
@notes_rendered = render_to_string "notes/list"
```

And then use it in the view you want.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that! Unfortunately, it doesn't work in this case, it looks like it has the same result as using `<%= render "notes/list", :remote => true %>` in the view. It doesn't go via the second controller action

Comment: I see... well given that I honestly think the idiomatic thing to do would be to add a new helper/service/whatever-pattern-you-like for extracting some functionality out of the NotesController into something like a NotesService, and call it in both controller actions.